# Filter two activities by date in same searchkit query

Tags: searchkit

I've built a stack exchange query

Search for activity type a

- return "with" contact, actiivity date- some custom data

I want to add in custom data from another activity (type B) that happened on the same day for the same contact

So i can include activity contacts activities- where type is type b

Some contacts have more than one type b activity

But the ones I'm interested in happen on the same day as the type a activity

Can I use activity date a as a filter/comparison to limit the type b activities that show in mmy search?

Does this even make sense?
Is it possible?

Any answers appreciated- here to learn!

Comment: Presumably 'stack exchange query' -> 'SearchKit query' :-)

Comment: lol. ha-ha!  yup!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SearchKit interface does not let you do that (yet!). But if you get the query close to what you want and export it into a `.mgd.php` in your extension, then you might be able to add in the missing condition by hand.

Comment: Thanks Aidan,

The data is going in via a drupal form so if push comes to shove I can just extract what I need from form results

Thought I'd check I wasn't missing a trick by asking here